# WordPress: Category RSS link on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

On single.php I want to display a list of categories, similar to the one using the_category but instead links to archive of these categories, I want links to RSS feed of these categories.

Is there a way to do this, without a plugin?

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>category/categoryname/feed">Category entry only (RSS)</a>
```

or

```
<?php wp_list_categories( $feed); ?>
```

You then can use exception rules within your snippet
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds / http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories